# How can I put a percentage character '%' at the end of an input section in Python 3?

Tags: python, input

Right now I'm working on a very basic program that should ask the user what percentage they want a value to increase by. I'm trying to make it so that the input prompt looks like:

> What percentage would you like this to increase by?
> [*blank for user input*]%

The idea is that there should be a percentage symbol '%' at the end of the input prompt, although I'm struggling to find a way of doing that, assuming that it's even possible.

At the moment I have the following code:

```
growth=int(input('What percentage per year do you expect the value to grow by?\n'))
```

Comment: that's not how input fields work, you can't

Comment: In a console I'm afraid that is not possible. You can make a simple UI to achieve it if required. A small tkinter box with the desired input fields

Comment: I wouldn't say it is impossible, but it would require a lot of coding and it may not behave the way you maybe think it would

Comment: I am sure this is possible with [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html), but that's gonna be quite complicated for just a small gain. With input fields, I don't see a way of making that work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
growth = int(input('What percentage per year do you expect the value to grow by?\n    %\r'))
```

This puts 4 spaces and then a percentage sign on the new line. The `\r` then tells the cursor to move back to the beginning of the line. This allows the user to override the characters. Of course, if they write more than 4 characters, they'll override the percentage sign.